# UIView animating to wrong position after being scaled while using constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uiviewanimation

So I'm trying to animate an `UILabel` to match another `UILabel` size and position. At first I was only working with the animation of the position part using constraints like this:

```
private lazy var constraintsForStateA: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
    firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    firstLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
]


private lazy var constraintsForStateB: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
    firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.leadingAnchor),
    firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.topAnchor)
]
```

So I basically have two arrays with these constraints above (`constraintsForStateA` and `constraintsForStateB`), and when I need to animate the position of my `firstLabel` I just do something like:

```
// From state A to state B
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self._constraintsUnselected)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self._constraintsSelected)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    } completion: { _ in
        self.firstLabel.alpha = 0
        self.secondLabel.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

So far this has been working exactly as I was expecting, but the part with the size is giving me some trouble, since I can't apply the same strategy to the text size I'm using a transform like this:

```
let scaleX = secondLabel.bounds.width / firstLabel.bounds.width
let scaleY = secondLabel.bounds.height / firstLabel.bounds.height
```

and then in the same .animate method above from state A to state B I do this:

```
firstLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)
```

and from state B to state A:

```
firstLabel.transform = .identity
```

Which works as I want but the problem I'm facing is that the position is no longer in the expected place. I think this is happening because the transformation is happening having in consideration the `anchorPoint` at the center of the label. I've tried sort of blindly making it work changing the `anchorPoint` to be at `(0,0)`, but it's not working either. I've lost 2 days on this already, any help or guidance is welcome!

Comment: To me, animating constraints is a super roundabout way of "animate an UILabel to match another UILabel size and position". Why not just have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`, and animate `firstLabel.frame = secondLabel.frame`?

Comment: Sorry if this seems pretty obvious, but I'm a beginner and at the moment I cannot use storyboards, so how would I vertically center my label inside another `UIView` without using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and then setting my constraints manually?

Comment: That's unrelated. You can still keep doing what you are doing to vertically centre the view. It's just when you want to animate, you obviously don't want to vertically centre your view anymore, so you can just disable the constraints, and set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true

Comment: @JalxP - it's not really clear what you're doing with the transform... Are you trying to move and "zoom" the label into position? Or, for example, does `secondLabel` have more text, so it's larger than `firstLabel`, and you want `firstLabel` to end up the same size as `secondLabel`?

Comment: Damn, @Sweeper I guess I was so formatted to always disable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` that it didn't occurred to me that I could disable it anywhere I would need to. As I always disabled it in my view declaration. This has helped a lot and basically solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you animate, it would be much simpler if you just forget about the constraints and just deal with frames:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraintsForStateA)
firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
    firstLabel.frame = secondLabel.frame
}
```

Then to transition from state B to A:

```
firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.constraintsForStateA)
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```